# How to put a limit in a function

Tags: python, function

I have a code that generates new theta value according to the function get_new_theta()
This is the code:

```
msg = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]


def get_new_theta(msg, theta):
    theta=random.randint(40,45)
    new_theta = [theta]
    for a, b in zip(msg[3::5], msg[4::5]):
        new_theta.append(new_theta[-1] + a + b)
    return new_theta

for i, theta in enumerate(get_new_theta(msg, 1)[:-1]):
    for j in range(5):
        print(theta, msg[i*5+j])
```

This is the example of the output

```
44 1
44 0
44 1
44 0
44 1
45 0
45 1
45 1
45 1
45 1
47 1
47 1
47 1
47 0
47 1
48 1
48 1
48 1
48 0
48 0
48 0
48 1
48 1
48 1
48 1
50 1
50 0
50 0
50 1
50 0
```

The problem is how to set up the limit so that the output of theta is not more than 45?
Let say if the value reach 47, the theta will be reset to the range of 40 to 45 and do recalculate it back using the given function.

Comment: why not use a simple `if` in your for-loop and do what you want whenever the resulting value is >45 there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function to this:

```
def get_new_theta(msg, theta):
    theta=random.randint(40,45)
    new_theta = [theta]
    for a, b in zip(msg[3::5], msg[4::5]):
        if (new_theta[-1] >= 45): new_theta[-1]=random.randint(40,45)
        new_theta.append(new_theta[-1] + a + b)
    return new_theta
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a value `theta` to stay between 40 and 45, you could execute this each time the value of `theta` is changed:

```
theta = theta % 5 + 40
```

The `theta % 5` reduces the value to something between `0` and `5`, and adding the `40` gets it in the desired range. The value `5` is the difference in the values defining the range `45 - 40`, while `40` is the lower end of the range.

This works well because the difference, `5`, divides evenly into the lower value, `40`. If that were not the case, you would probably want something slightly more complicated:

```
theta = (theta - 40) % 5 + 40
```

Comment: You probably need `modulo 6` instead of `5` to reach `45`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: No, `5` is correct. If `theta` is just below `45` the modulus will be a value just below `5` so adding the `40` gives just below `45`, which is what is wanted. If I used `6` then a value just below `42` would have a modulus just below `6` and adding `40` would result in just below `46`, which is too high.

Comment: Aren't all these values integers?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your for loop to test if the value is over 45. You would assign the value to be added to `new_theta` to a variable, then test if that value if over 45. If so, calculate again. You can do this by adding a `while value > 45:` to your for loop. Your function would then look like this:

```
def get_new_theta(msg, theta):
    theta=random.randint(40,45)
    new_theta = [theta]
    for a, b in zip(msg[3::5], msg[4::5]):
        new_value = 46
        while new_value > 45:
            new_value = new_theta[-1] + a + b
        new_theta.append(new_value)
    return new_theta
```